# Implement Context-Free Grammar for $L=\{a^n b^m \mid n \neq 2m\}$

Tags: context-free

I am trying to implement a context-free grammar for $L=\{a^n b^m \mid n \neq 2m\}$.

I have a difficulty trying to implement it because I don't know how to ensure that $n \neq 2m$.

I can easily implement $n=2m$ but the other way around doesn't seem intuitive. How can I approach this problem?

Comment: If n \neq 2m then n is equal to either 2m+k or 2m-k for some positive integer k. Try working from that.

Comment: Welcome to [cs.SE]! Note that you can use LaTeX here to typeset mathematics in a more readable way. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands) for a short introduction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hint:* A string of the form $a^nb^m$ where $n \neq 2m$ can be either

- A string with too many $a$'s, or
- A string with too few $a$'s

Create production rules for each of these cases.