# Is $B=\{a^n b^m \mid n \not= 2m\}$ a context free grammar

Tags: formal-languages, context-free

I was trying to find a grammar that generates $B=\{a^n b^m \mid n \not= 2m\}$ but I couldn't so I'm not sure that it is a CFG.
This is what I did :
$$
S\rightarrow X \mid aX \mid a \mid b \mid \epsilon
$$
$$
X\rightarrow aa Xb \mid Y \mid Z
$$
$$
Y\rightarrow aY \mid a
$$
$$
Z\rightarrow bZ \mid b
$$

Comment: Now it generates $ab|a|b|\epsilon|(aa(a|b)^+b)$, which is still not what you want.

Comment: This language has been around for some time, see [Generating grammar for the given language](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/75266/4287) or [Implement Context-Free Grammar for $L=\{a^nb^m \mid n\neq 2m\}$](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/66980/implement-context-free-grammar-for-l-an-bm-mid-n-neq-2m).

Answer (score 3):

If $n \neq 2m$ then either $n < 2m$ or $n > 2m$.

A grammar for the former case is:
$$
S_1 \to XY \mid aXY\\
X \to aaXb \mid \varepsilon  \\
Y \to bY \mid b
$$
where $X$ generates all words of the form $a^{2k} b^k$  for some positive $k$.

A grammar for the latter case is:
$$
S_2 \to ZX \mid Z\\
X \to aaXb \mid \varepsilon \\
Z \to aZ \mid a
$$

A grammar for your language can be obtained as the union of the above two grammars.